# Need to create a plot with a set of data stored in file

Tags: matlab, octave

Hello I'm a octave beginner. I have a data set in a file as bellow:

```
12 20 3 1 \n
12 3 4 5
.......
```

These are the four co-ordinates of a rectangle. I need to plot all of these rectangles in a graph. I tried to read the file with following piece of code but I'm getting stuck.

```
fid=fopen("priminfo.txt");
A = testscan (fid, '%f %f %f %f %*[^\n]')
```

Any comments on that will be really helpful

Comment: Is there actually a \n in the file?  That's usually how a program indicates a newline.  If you actually see \n, then the software that outputs this data is broken and should be fixed.

Comment: I have a new version of it now. So, it'll be a new line.

Comment: Now you need to edit your question and explain what's not working and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: thanks, i got it working with load('priminfo.txt')

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
A = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f');
```

Actually, so should this

```
A = load('priminfo.txt');
```

Comment: `load` can't be used if `textscan` has `%*[^\n]` (skip the remaining of the line) as the OP suggested.

Comment: He doesn't need it, since his format is just 4 floats per line.

Comment: true - my bad - %*[^\n] is spurious in the question